# How can I open an unzipped map file

Tags: r, gdal, ogr, rgdal

I am trying to read a zipped map file to use as a map overlay on contours, but I do not seem to be able to unzip the file. Below are the commands I have;

```
library(rgdal)
setwd("C:/R_Progs")
unzip("ZMB_adm.zip")
zmb <- readOGR(dsn = "C:/R_Progs", layer = "ZMB_adm")
zmb2 <- fortify(zmb)
```

I want to use zmb2 as a base map in my plot. The zip file and the script are in the same directory.
Below is what I get:

```
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv) :
```

Cannot open layer
But I do see the unzip command works because I see 4 new files with dbf, prj, shp and shx extensions

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
unzip("ZMB_adm.zip", exdir="ZBM_adm")
zmb <- readOGR(dsn = "C:/R_Progs/ZBM_adm", layer="ZMB_ADM0")

## OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
## Source: "C:/R_Progs/ZBM_adm", layer: "ZMB_ADM0"
## with 1 features and 2 fields
## Feature type: wkbPolygon with 2 dimensions
```

The `extdir` parameter will keep the shapefiles tidy in their own directory.

The reason for the `ZMB_ADM0` is that there are multiple shapefiles:

```
ZMB_ADM0.SHP
ZMB_ADM1.SHP
ZMB_ADM2.SHP
```

each with their own layers:

```
INFO: Open of `ZMB_ADM0.SHP'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: ZMB_ADM0 (Polygon)

INFO: Open of `ZMB_ADM1.SHP'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: ZMB_ADM1 (Polygon)

INFO: Open of `ZMB_ADM2.SHP'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: ZMB_ADM2 (Polygon)
```

Which one you use will depend on what level of administrative boundaries you need:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

map0 <- readOGR(dsn = "C:/R_Progs/ZBM_adm", layer="ZMB_ADM0")
map1 <- readOGR(dsn = "C:/R_Progs/ZBM_adm", layer="ZMB_ADM1")
map2 <- readOGR(dsn = "C:/R_Progs/ZBM_adm", layer="ZMB_ADM2")

map0@data$id <- rownames(map0@data)
map1@data$id <- rownames(map1@data)
map2@data$id <- rownames(map2@data)

adm_labs0 <- data.frame(id=rownames(map0@data), adm0=map0@data$ADM0)
adm_labs1 <- data.frame(id=rownames(map1@data), adm1=map1@data$ADM1)
adm_labs2 <- data.frame(id=rownames(map2@data), adm2=map2@data$ADM2)

map_0 <- fortify(map0)
map_1 <- fortify(map1)
map_2 <- fortify(map2)

map_0 <- merge(map_0, adm_labs0)
map_1 <- merge(map_1, adm_labs1)
map_2 <- merge(map_2, adm_labs2)

map0 <- readOGR(dsn = "C:/R_Progs/ZBM_adm", layer="ZMB_ADM0")
map1 <- readOGR(dsn = "C:/R_Progs/ZBM_adm", layer="ZMB_ADM1")
map2 <- readOGR(dsn = "C:/R_Progs/ZBM_adm", layer="ZMB_ADM2")

map0@data$id <- rownames(map2@data)
map1@data$id <- rownames(map1@data)
map2@data$id <- rownames(map2@data)

adm_labs0 <- data.frame(id=rownames(map0@data), adm0=map0@data$ADM0)
adm_labs1 <- data.frame(id=rownames(map1@data), adm1=map1@data$ADM1)
adm_labs2 <- data.frame(id=rownames(map2@data), adm2=map2@data$ADM2)

map_0 <- fortify(map0)
map_1 <- fortify(map1)
map_2 <- fortify(map2)

map_0 <- merge(map_0, adm_labs0)
map_1 <- merge(map_1, adm_labs1)
map_2 <- merge(map_2, adm_labs2)

g0 <- ggplot(map_0, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "grey50", aes(fill=adm0), size=0.125)+
  labs(x="",y="")+ theme_bw() + labs(title="ADM0") +
  coord_fixed() + theme(legend.position="none")

g1 <- ggplot(map_1, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "grey50", aes(fill=adm1), size=0.125)+
  labs(x="",y="")+ theme_bw() + labs(title="ADM1") +
  coord_fixed() + theme(legend.position="none")

g2 <- ggplot(map_2, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "grey50", aes(fill=adm2), size=0.125)+
  labs(x="",y="")+ theme_bw() + labs(title="ADM2") +
  coord_fixed() + theme(legend.position="none")

grid.arrange(g0, g1, g2, ncol=3)
```

[image: d]

Comment: you have really done more than I asked for. Thanks so much, though I have another problem of my own and that is I have more than one version of R so i get the error: "Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class function"

Comment: Just one more request @hrbrmstr, when I run your code above as is, I get : "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "id", value = c("0", "1", "2", "3",  : replacement has 72 rows, data has 1. I wonder if you can spend your precious to advise me where the problem could be, otherwise the folder os shapefiles is created and populated.